# implementation of post redirect get in java web

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, post-redirect-get

am i implementing the post redirect get approach in java web. i have this index.jsp which i can add information to database.

```
<form action="servlet" method="post>
<input type="text" placeholder="itemname"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="itemprice"/>
<input type="submit" value="add item"/>
</form>
```

and in servlet i process the username and password

```
//returns a boolean if success or not
if(processItem(itemname,itemprice)){
     response.sendRedirect("secondservlet?ADD=success");
}
```

and in the secondservlet

```
if(request.getParameter("ADD").equals("SUCCESS"))
 request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

am i doing it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
am i doing it right?
```

You are sending a POST, then redirecting, which results in a GET. If that is what you were trying to do, then yes, you are doing it right.

Note that your second servlet should probably check if `getParameter(..)` returns `null`. You might get to the second servlet from some other call that doesn't include any request parameters.

Comment: in the second servlet should i use request dispatcher or redirect?because i am trying to avoid the conform message when i want to refresh the page.

Comment: @KerPPag Are you trying to do POST-REDIRECT-GET-REDIRECT-GET? No, then don't redirect in your GET.

Comment: @KerPPag Lol, you're welcome. Consider looking into what a Redirect is. It's basically just an HTTP response with a 302 status code and a `Location` header.